# Count Total Subarrays having NEGATIVE PRODUCT in O(n)

Tags: c++, math, sub-array

In a array consisting of integer ( negative , positive and zero )
task is to find **Total Number of subarrays**  whose product is ***Negative*** .

If i find all subarray and then check for negative product , it will go in **O(n^2)**.

```
long long n,a[200001],i,neg[200001],j;
long long totalneg=0; //prefix array to store number of negative element
cin>>n;
a[0]=0,neg[0]=0;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{   cin>>a[i];
  if(a[i]<0)
   neg[i]=neg[i-1]+1;
else
 neg[i]=neg[i-1];
}

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
    {
        if( (neg[j]-neg[i-1]) %2 !=0 )
         totalneg++;
    }
}
cout<<totalneg;
```

So how can I find it in  **O(n)** time.

Comment: Please, show us code you have so far.

Comment: I don't know what time complexity you will have in that case, but you could: 1) get the array size (let's say `n`); 2) find all negative values; 3) Let's get to the algorithm ...
If you have an odd number of negative values, then you surely have a negative product, and that is independent from the number of positive values. So you have to use the combination of all positive values and the combination of all possible odd multiplications from negative numbers.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a homework writing service I'm afraid. Show us what you've done, explain what isn't working and we might be able to fix it.An array will have a negative product if it has an odd number of negative numbers if that helps?

Comment: Two observations: (1) your naive solution is O(n^3), not O(n^2) [you're forgetting the cost of computing the product]; (2) think dynamic programming.

Comment: Moreover it would be great if you can write the solution of yours having time complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: Simple googling could help you. Try [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-subarrays-product-less-k/)

Comment: There are two examples. Check the below one

Answer (score 0):

Starting with first value: If it is negative, you found one of those sub arrays, if it is positive, you found one subarray with positive sum (coming ot zero later).

Then lets's consider next value: If negative/positive, you found another such sub array. However, you can combine them with all subarrays you found so far!

If you have found *n<sub>p</sub>* positive sub arrays, you get another *n<sub>p</sub>* positive sub arrays if current value is positive, or another *n<sub>p</sub>* negative arrays, if current value is negative, analogously for the count of negative *n<sub>n</sub>* arrays, just that you get new arrays with negative product for positive value and new arrays with positive product for negative value.

Special value of zero: This value contained in any subarray will produce zero as product, it doesn't matter at all any more what the other factors are. So you can stop at this point, adding *n<sub>n</sub>* to some total count and re-start with *n<sub>p</sub>* and *n<sub>n</sub>* being zero.

Having considered all numbers in the array, don't forget to add the latestly calculated *n<sub>n</sub>* to the total sum.

Now all that's left is forging this algorithm into code, which is left to you... If you should run into trouble doing so, feel free to ask a new question, providing the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached this problem was the following :

We only care about the sign of the number, since we are not asked to calculate the actual results of the multiplications we can easily **convert the input to 1's and -1's** where each one represents a positive and a negative integer respectively if the given array was {1,-2,3} now it's {1,-1,1}.

Now the key for solving this is using a prefix multiplication array to keep track of the answer since  a subarray from [ i , j ] has a negative result if and only if **prefix[ i ] * prefix[ j ] < 0**  therefore :

**answer = #negative_numbers_prefix * #positive_numbers_prefix**

The C++ algorithm would look something like this :

```
int main() {
int n,value;
cin>>n;
int positive=1,negative=0,prefix[n]; 
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>value; 
    if (value>0){
        prefix[i]=1; 
    }else{
        prefix[i]=-1; 
    }

    if (i>0){
        prefix[i]*=prefix[i-1]; 
    }

    if (prefix[i]==1){ 
        positive++; 
    }else{
        negative++; 
    }
} 
int answer=negative*positive;
cout<<answer<<endl;
```

}

**NOTE** : there may be some variants of this problem such as calculating the number of positive subarray multiplication instead of negative in this cases there's a very handy formula for calculating all possible subarrays which is ( N * ( N + 1 )) / 2 ) so if you want to calculate the positive ones you just need to subtract the negative ones to the total : **( N * ( N + 1 ) ) / 2  - answer**.

Answer (score 0):

"If the array contains the integer {-1 , 2, -3}. Then it will give output 4. But if array contains the integer {-1, 2, -3, 0}. Then it will give output 6 as per the above solution. 
I have removed the bug by restricting the condition and my code is"

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t-->0){
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            float a[] = new float[n];
            long arr[] = new long[n];
            long pos = 1,neg = 0;
            String str[] = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                a[i] = Float.parseFloat(str[i]);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                if(a[i]==0) {
                    break;
                }
                if(a[i]>0){
                    arr[i] = 1;
                }else{
                    arr[i] = -1;
                }
                if(i>0){
                    arr[i] = arr[i]*arr[i-1];
                }
                if (arr[i]==1){ 
                    pos++; 
                }else{
                    neg++; 
                }
            }
            long ans = (pos*neg)%1000000007;
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
    }
}
```